# Some Hybris first time use after installlation issues

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

[2015-10-13:2043] 
Here is a screen shot of the installed extensions...
[image: Screen shot of the Hybris installed extensions from the HAC]

=========
I think there is a problem with the initialisation script..

=========

I have now installed hybris5.6.0.2:

1. I have now been able to run the Hybris Administration Console
   [localhost:9001]
2. I have logged in.
3. I have ran the Initialisation, because being a first time installation, except of taking about an hour to complete, it took about 1 minute 30 sec to complete. I suspect something is wrong.
4. It has been about six months since I worked with hybris, and I have forgotten the URLs for the hMC, and for the MCC... for the MCC, is it:

http://localhost:9001/mcc??

for the hMC is it:

http://localhost:9001/hMC??

Any suggestions?

Comment: see my answer below. btw. the initialization time heavily depends on what extensions you have in your localextensions.xml.. all the accelerator extensions contain a lot if sample data (e.g. electronicstore, powertools etc) which take some time to import. your 1:30mins are probably ok as you run a pretty empty hybris with barely any extensions.

Comment: <extension dir="${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}/custom/training/trainingcore"/>
 <extension dir="${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}/custom/training/trainingfacades"/>
 <extension dir="${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}/custom/training/trainingtest"/>
 <extension dir="${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}/custom/training/trainingstorefront"/>
 <extension dir="${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}/custom/training/trainingfulfilmentprocess"/>
 <extension dir="${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}/custom/training/traininginitialdata"/>
 <extension dir="${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}/custom/training/trainingcockpits"/> i have these many extensions...how long will it take to initialize

Comment: My Initialization gets stuck in localizing types

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the hmc/mmc extensions in your $HYBRIS_HOME/config/localextensions.xml 
You need to have them declared as

```
<extension name='mcc' />
<extension name="hmc" />
```

The urls for accessing them are

- http://localhost:9001/hmc/hybris
- (or use: http://localhost:9001/hmc/hybris?wid=MC0x0, the parameters ensure that the hmc window gets opened in your current tab and not in a separate window)
- http://localhost:9001/mmc

In order to get it to work you will have to:

1. first have to add those extensions (see above)
2. `ant clean all` (from within $HYBRIS_HOME/bin/platform, don't forget to also set the ant environment via ". ./setantenv.sh" or "setantenv.bat")
3. `ant initialize`

Then you should be able to access the hmc and mmc.

However, you don't seem to have a lot of extensions at all installed. 
Not sure what you are trying to do.. 
If you plan to setup a new "application" by developing your own extensions, e.g. based on the accelerator (or other examples) you should take a look at how to generate those via ext-gen.
(see e.g. https://wiki.hybris.com/display/accdoc/Customizing+the+Accelerator+with+extgen+and+modulegen)

Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

By default under Hybris 5.6 the generated **localextensions.xml** is now totally empty (it used to be not) :

```
<path dir="${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}" />
<extension name="yempty" />
```

When you run 'ant all' you can actually see what extensions are loaded :

```
[echo] core 5.6.0.1 [p*cib]
[echo] testweb 5.6.0.1 [p*w]
[echo] scripting 5.6.0.1 [p*ci]
[echo] paymentstandard 5.6.0.1 [p*ci]
[echo] mediaweb 5.6.0.1 [p*cw]
[echo] maintenanceweb 5.6.0.1 [p*w]
[echo] deliveryzone 5.6.0.1 [p*ci]
[echo] commons 5.6.0.1 [p*ci]
[echo] processing->(scripting,commons) 5.6.0.1 [p*ci]
[echo] impex->processing 5.6.0.1 [p*ci]
[echo] validation->impex 5.6.0.1 [p*ci]
[echo] catalog->(validation,commons) 5.6.0.1 [p*cib]
[echo] europe1->(impex,catalog) 5.6.0.1 [p*ci]
[echo] platformservices->(paymentstandard,impex,deliveryzone,europe1,processing) 5.6.0.1 [p*cb]
[echo] workflow->(catalog,platformservices,processing,commons) 5.6.0.1 [p*ci]
[echo] hac->(impex,catalog,processing,platformservices) 5.6.0.1 [p*w]
[echo] comments->(workflow,impex,catalog,processing) 5.6.0.1 [p*ci]
[echo] advancedsavedquery->(impex,catalog,processing) 5.6.0.1 [p*ci]
[echo] yempty 5.6.0.1 [cibw] path:/Users/*****/Workspace/hybris/hybris/bin/ext-template/yempty
```

Now the question is what do you want ? Do you want to run a B2C site ? If yes the best way is to run 'ant modulegen' and then add your own extensions, or if you simply want out of the box default sites, add those lines under your **localextensions.xml** file :

```
<extension name='apparelstore' />
<extension name='electronicsstore' />

<extension name='yacceleratorcore' />
<extension name='yacceleratorinitialdata' />
<extension name='yacceleratorfacades' />
<extension name='yacceleratorcockpits' />
<extension name='yacceleratorstorefront' />
```

By doing this you will have out of the box store fronts and HMC / Cockpits.

Answer (score 0):

Post the hybris 5.5.1 version, there have been significant changes in the platform. The recipe concept has been introduced for the installation of extensions. This recipe is nothing but a .gradle file which contains information about the extensions to be written in the localextensions.xml and the property files (local.properties and custom.properties) to be modified. This is probably introduced with the intention of the "Separation of Concerns" ideology of hybris. Please find below the link which contains the information about recipes

https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/Sample+Scenarios+Installation