# how to configure HMC in Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am new to Hybris. I am able to configure Hybris Administration Console and access the sections by following wiki.hybris documents.

I dont find a section to configure the Hybris Management Console (HMC). I get 404 error when I access the URL http://localhost:9001/hmc. Please let me know where to find to get this URL working.

**UPDATE**

I am sorry for not giving enough information in my original post. 
I am using Hybris Commerce Suite 5.7.0.8 and followed the steps mentioned in wiki.hybris.

I executed the following commands in CMD.

- setantenv.bat
- ant clean all
- hybrisserver.bat
- Then logged into http://localhost:9001/ using admin credentials
- Under Platform--> Initialization, I initialized to recreate the new
  tables.

Apart from the above, I did not do any other steps. I noticed that the extensions under HMC in Platform-->Extension, are all marked as X. Please refer to the attached image.

[image: HMC under extension in HAC]

Comment: Which hybris version?

Comment: Can you show us your localextensions.xml file? Maybe put it on pastebin for us or something. Looks like you might not have all the right extensions in there.

Comment: Also, please provide a copy of your local.properties file so we can check that too.

Comment: @kabadisha. There was nothing in localextensions.xml and the following line is there in local.properties. 
# place your custom properties into this file instead of modifying the project.properties
mykey=myvalue

#hac.webroot=/hac

Comment: @kabadisha, Can you please point me, where I can find all the extensions (names) that can be mentioned in the localextensions.xml

Comment: I think I know what's going on - see my new answer :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the hmc as part of your `localextensions.xml` file... see the answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33110971/932201

After adding the hmc extension you have to run an update running system from the hac (or re-initialize).

Note though that the hmc is the old backoffice application, in more recent versions it had first been depracted and finally been removed.
The new backoffice application is called backoffice and its url is by default:

```
http://localhost:9001/backoffice
```

(you would also have to add the `backoffice` extension to your localextensions.xml file to make it available)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. After adding the extensions, it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Perform the following steps :

Step 1 : Add the following main modules in localextensions.xml

```
    <extension name="admincockpit" />
    <extension name="backoffice" />
    <extension name="cockpit" />
    <extension name="hmc" />
    <extension name="mcc" />
    <extension name="platformhmc" />
```

Step 2: Run ant clean all

Step 3 : Run update from HAC

Answer (score 0):

The hMC is usually available on http://localhost:9001/hmc (or /hmc/hybris if you don't want it opening in a pop up).

I'd suggest checking your server logs (~YOUR_HYBRIS_DIR/hybris/log/tomcat/console.log) and seeing if there's any errors in it.

Comment: There are no errors in the log file. Please refer the image that I attached as the extensions under HMC is all X

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have not altered the property hmc.webroot. It should be set to /hmc by default, but you can try explicitly setting it in your local.properties file like this:

```
hac.webroot=/hac
hmc.webroot=/hmc
```

Also you need to initialize the system before you can access anything other than the HAC.

You can do this either using your browser via the HAC or using ant:

```
ant clean all initialize
```

You can read all about Hybris' initialize and update processes here:
https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/Initializing+and+Updating+the+hybris+Commerce+Suite

Hope this helps

Comment: I did initialize in the browser before I log into HAC. Please refer my updated post for more details.

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of Hybris they have introduced an installer script that sets up the basics for you. What this means though is that if you just go right ahead and simply run ant all, you will get a localextensions.xml file with almost everything disabled.

What you should do is install hybris using the installer script and one of the recipies. See here:

https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/Sample+Scenarios+Installation

This will generate you a decent starting configuration for what ever you want to do with hybris.

For example, when I install the recipe **b2c_acc** (B2C Accelerator), I get the following localextensions.xml file generated:

```
<hybrisconfig xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='../bin/platform/resources/schemas/extensions.xsd'>
    <extensions>
        <path dir='${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}' autoload='false' />
        <extension name='mcc' />
        <extension name='backoffice' />
        <extension name='commercesearchbackoffice' />
        <extension name='commerceservicesbackoffice' />
        <extension name='solrfacetsearchbackoffice' />
        <extension name='solrserver' />
        <extension name='yacceleratorcockpits' />
        <extension name='yacceleratorinitialdata' />
        <extension name='yacceleratorfulfilmentprocess' />
        <extension name='yacceleratorstorefront' />
        <extension name='yaddon' />
        <extension name='ycommercewebservices' />
        <extension name='electronicsstore' />
        <extension name='apparelstore' />
        <extension name='liveeditaddon' />
        <extension name='acceleratorwebservicesaddon' />
    </extensions>
</hybrisconfig>
```

Once you have done this, I also strongly recommend installing MySQL and using that as your database rather than the default HSQLDB approach as it is much, much faster. See here:

https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/MySQL

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Go to  http://localhost:9001/mcc (log as an admin) you will find all links of your current Hybris installation.

What version of Hybris are you using ? Do you see the hmc extension when you go to the HAC ?

Edit:
With 5.7 the default localextensions.xml is mostly empty by default, you will need to run an installer like '. install.sh -r b2c_acc_plus' from your installer directory (first level of your Hybris installation)

Comment: I am getting 404 error when I go to :9001/mcc. I am using 5.7.0.8. The extensions are disabled under HMC. Please see my post where I attached the screenshot.